# Does an idle session on the GCP console ever timeout?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm being asked by my security team when an idle session is terminated. I haven't been able to find an answer. I don't think I'm ever idle for that long but it would be good to know.

If there is a session time-out, what is the default time?

Comment: How long you stay logged in to the console depends on whether you remain logged in to your Google account. Are you instead referring to [SSH from the browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser)?

Comment: This question could use clarity if you're talking about the a terminal console or the web console used to administer the cloud project.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/general-tips#communicatewithinternet),there's an idle connection timeout.

> Note that idle connections are tracked for a maximum of 10 minutes, after which their traffic is subject to firewall rules, including the implied deny ingress rule.

This [community post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078348/google-cloud-ssh-timeout-how-to-increase-session-time?answertab=oldest#tab-top) seems to have answered this as well.

Comment: The information above is only for GCE and not the GCP Console.

Answer (score 0):

The timeout feature is available now. BTW, it's absolute length of session duration (whether idle or not), not **idle** timeout. See this blog:

- [Introducing time-bound Session Length defaults to improve your security posture](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/improve-security-posture-with-time-bound-session-length)

This comment can shed more light on a related feature:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35904790#comment36